# Magento 2 Checkout error when logged in

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have an error on checkout page if I am logged in. But its does not occur if I am not logged in. On the checkout page I am getting the following error:

> **Error occurred during "shipping_address" processing. Error occurred**
>   **during "save_in_address_book" processing. Invalid type for value: "1".
>   Expected Type: "int".**

I believe this is related to data being sent from the browser to magento is invalid but I cannot find a solution. I am running Magento 2.1.0 and upgraded to 2.1.2 to test and got the same error.

Can anyone offer any assistance? TIA

Answer (score 3):

In your shipping.js file, search for save_in_address_book and

Replace

> shippingAddress.save_in_address_book = true;

with

> ShippingAddress.save_in_address_book = 1;

And replace

> addressData.save_in_address_book = this.saveInAddressBook;

with

> addressData.save_in_address_book = this.saveInAddressBook ? 1 : 0;

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

with the transition to version 2.1 changes were made in **shipping.js** file. 
For example:
[2.0.9](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.9/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js#L166) -
[2.1.2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js#L187)

If you have defined it in his subject and made the transition - may have problems

Comment: Thanks, but how can i fix those shipping.js errors in magento2.1.5 help me great.

Comment: can any one sove this issue